# dataTables properly parsed json response from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I am trying to create a table using datatables 1.10 jquery plugin. i am trying to use:

```
$(function(){
$('#example').dataTable(
{
                    "ajax":{
                            url:"getTicketList.php",
                            "columns": [
                                    { "data": "id" },
                                    { "data": "company" }
                            ]
                    }
});
});
```

and getTicketList.php

```
foreach ($ticketList as $k => $v){
    $tickets['data'][$a]['id'] = $v['ticket_id'];
    $tickets['data'][$a]['company'] = $v['listed_company'];
    $a++;
}
echo json_encode($tickets);
```

which results in:

```
{"data":{"1":{"id":"20523","company”:”Acme Inc”},”2”:{“id":"23148","company”:”Walmart”}}}
```

and the html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Company</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Yet i get no data in table.  Any thoughts why? this is my first attempt at using datatables.....

with ChrisV's suggestion I now get the following error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=ticketList - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

resolved.  I had some extra code floating around on the page.

Comment: Is the JSON real part of actual output (exact copy) or you wrote it as example? I ask beacuse it contains different quotes : `”` & `"`

Comment: the json was a copy and paste, they syntax of quotes is correct.  I edited values to hide what data is really there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `columns` property should appear directly in the `.dataTable(` declaration, not nested in the `ajax` property.

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisV is right. So it will go something like this:

```
<code>
$(function(){
$('#example').dataTable(
{
                    "ajax":{
                            url:"getTicketList.php"
                    },
                      "columns": [
                                    { "data": "id" },
                                    { "data": "company" }
                            ]
});
});
</code>
```